# Function object in object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function-pointers, dom-events

I am trying to implement a model in Javascript in a object-oriented manner. Say I have object X with bunch of functions. I want to have an object array "in X" that some of its fields point to some functions in X. Here is the example of what I tried:

```
function X(){

this.open = function(e){...};
this.run = function(e){...};
this.close = function(e){...};
//...

this.STATES = {
    1: {name : "opening", applyAction : this.open},
    2: {name : "runing", applyAction : this.run},
    3: {name : "closing", applyAction : this.close},
    //...
};

this.currentState = this.STATES[1];

//...

this.update = function(e){
    //...
    currentState.applyAction(e);
    //...
}
```

However this approach does not work as expected. I cant figure out what is wrong, also if you have alternative way of doing the same thing I would truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because 'this' inside of the following code points to the literal object you're defining, not the intended 'this':

```
this.STATES = {
    1: {name : "opening", applyAction : this.open},
    2: {name : "runing", applyAction : this.run},
    3: {name : "closing", applyAction : this.close},
    //...
};
```

Try

```
function X() {
    var self = this;

    this.open = function() {
        // ...
    }

    this.STATES = {
        1: {name: "opening", applyAction: self.open},
        ...
```

I'd also read up about Javascript scoping.

Comment: Thank you very much! it was a great help

Comment: I have written a tutorial on the very same point. The behavior of 'this' pointer is explained here: https://rahuldotout.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/professional-javascript-part-6-objects-without-classes/2/